# selective filter of join of three tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables Table1, Table2 and Table3.

Table1 has one to many relation with Table2. Table2 has one to many relation with Table3.

Say table1 has

```
-------------
t1key
-------------
a
b

Table2 has 
-------------
t1key | t2key
--------------
a        c
a        d
b        x
b        y


Table 3
------------
t2key | t3key
-------------
c      e
c      f
c      g
d      h
d      i
d      j
x      m
x      n
x      o
y      p
y      q
y      r
```

I want the join the three tables so that it returns only the first unique match for t2key in table3

The result of join should be

```
a c  e
a d  h
b x  m
b y  p
```

Currently my app does a join of all three table which returns all possible rows. I need to filter this out with the above condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.t1Key = T2.t1Key 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T3 ON T2.t2Key = T3.t2Key
```

Comment: Please, watch formatting. Even better, write a schema (`CREATE TABLE` and some `INSERT TABLE` statements) or provide an example of your tables on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It is hard to answer SQL questions if we can't see the data properly.

Comment: Please let us know which RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  t2.t1Key, 
  t2.t2key, 
  MIN(t3.t3key) t3key
FROM Table1 AS T1  
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.t1Key = T2.t1Key 
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.t2Key = T3.t2Key
GROUP BY t2.t1Key, 
         t2.t2key;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e2b/7)

This will give you:

```
| T1KEY | T2KEY | T3KEY |
-------------------------
|     a |     c |     e |
|     a |     d |     h |
|     b |     x |     m |
|     b |     y |     p |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause and use `MIN()` for first

```
SELECT t2.t1key, t2.t2key, MIN(t3.t3key) AS t3key
FROM Table1 AS T1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.t1Key = T2.t1Key 
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.t2Key = T3.t2Key
GROUP BY t2.t1Key, t2.t2key;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf48d4/10)

If you want to show only data which are available in every table then use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.
e.g. suppose there is a row in `Table2` `'b', 'q'`.
Then if you use `LEFT JOIN` it will show result like this

```
| T1KEY | T2KEY |  T3KEY |
--------------------------
|     a |     c |      e |
|     a |     d |      h |
|     b |     q | (null) | <-- It will show null value too
|     b |     x |      m |
|     b |     y |      p |
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/164a2/1)

Using `INNER JOIN` it will not show that record

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/164a2/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table1 table
(
    t1 char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @table1
SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' 


DECLARE @table2 table
(
    t1 char(1),
    t2 char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @table2
SELECT 'a', 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'x' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'y' 

DECLARE @table3 table
(
    t1 char(1),
    t2 char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @table3
SELECT 'c', 'e' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'f' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'g' UNION ALL

SELECT 'd', 'h' UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 'i' UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 'j' UNION ALL

SELECT 'x', 'm' UNION ALL
SELECT 'x', 'n' UNION ALL
SELECT 'x', 'o' UNION ALL

SELECT 'y', 'p' UNION ALL
SELECT 'y', 'q' UNION ALL
SELECT 'y', 'r' 



SELECT 

    t1.t1,
    t2.t2,
    min(t3.t2)
FROM @table2 t2
INNER JOIN @table3 t3
ON t3.t1 = t2.t2
INNER JOIN @table1 t1
ON t1.t1 = t2.t1
GROUP BY t1.t1,
    t2.t2
```

Comment: @user1971858 have you checked my logic

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.t1key,t2.t2key,t3.t3key 
FROM Table1 t1  
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1Key = t2.t1Key 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t2.t2Key = t3.t2Key
group by t2.t1key,t2.t2key;
```