# Mysql Select only returns 1 entry per mapping

Tags: mysql, select

I have 5 Relations:  A, B, A_B, C, D.
What I'm trying is to get the A&B pairs and select further informations about

```
SELECT A.aName, B.bName, C.cName, D.dName 
FROM `A` , `B` , `A&B` , `C` , `D`
WHERE B.bName= A_B.bName
AND A.aName = A_B.aName
AND A.cName = C.cName
AND C.dName = D.dName
```

But this works not the way I thought, it only represents one entry per A, even if there are more A_B mappings for A.

UPDATE2:

TableA has

```
-------------
t1key | t2key
--------------
a1        c1
a2        c2
a3        c1
a4        c1


Table B
------------
t3key | t4key
-------------
b1      XXX
b2      XXX
b3      XXX
b4      XXX
b5      XXX


Table A&B
------------
t1key | t3key
-------------
a1      b1
a1      b2
a1      b3
a3      b1
a4      b2


Table C
------------
t2key | t4key
-------------
c1      d1
c2      d2
c3      d1
c4      d3
c5      d1
```

Result should be

```
a1   b1 c1 d1
a1   b2 c1 d1
a1   b3 c1 d1
a3   b1 c2 d2
a4   b2 c1 d1
```

As you see a1 has 3 entrys in this result...

Comment: can you please add sample records with desired result?

Comment: I would recommend you start using ANSI standard `JOIN`s

Comment: that's basically an inner join and you'll only get records where **ALL** of those `and` clauses are true.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is avoid "old fashioned" implicit join syntax and learn to use explicit syntax (joins that use an `ON` condition).  That will make everything much easier to understand.  Next learn about the different types of joins, in particular the `LEFT JOIN`.

With that in mind, see if this does what you want:

```
SELECT A.aName, B.bName, C.cName, D.dName
FROM  `A&B`
LEFT JOIN `A`
ON   A.aName = A_B.aName
LEFT JOIN `B`
ON   B.bName = A_B.bName
LEFT JOIN `C` 
ON   C.cName = A.cName
LEFT JOIN `D`
ON  D.dName = C.dName
```

Comment: I tried it but it also kills double entrys of A. Even if I remove the joins for C and D. My orignal code works if I remove C and D but I need C and D...

Comment: Update your question and show a brief sample of the records in each table and an example of the result you want.  It's not clear what you mean by "double entrys".  You don't need to give a lot of detail, just enough to illustrate your question.

Comment: @user1735225 Please try and update your question again; take a look at this other question to see how to display sample data and expected results:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14290760/1275871

Comment: @user1735225 Try again.  Show the actual column names from each of your tables (aName, bName, etc., not t1key, t2key).  Also include your table D.  Remember, the only thing we can see is what you describe in the question.

Comment: Sorry but I missed the deadline.... the goal was xlst so hopefully this "bug" doesn't count. thanks for your help and patience.